# Show HighCharts tooltip when chart loads

Tags: user-interface, highcharts

I am sing Highcharts to show years against premium amount of loan. I am showing a crosshair and tooltip when user hovers on chart area. However, I want to show this when the chart loads initially (without / before moving mouse). Is there any way to do this? to make the tooltip sticky, I used below code and it works (except IE8). Simillarly, looking for displaying it on load.

```
chart.tooltip.hide = function () { };
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Refresh the tooltip with the point at which you wish to show the tooltip at load

```
chart.tooltip.refresh(chart.series[1].points[2]);

// If the tooltip.shared=true, the parameter is array of points
chart.tooltip.refresh([chart.series[1].points[2]]);
```

[Show Tooltip on Load @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/t9hf1j46/)

Read More @ [Customizing Highcharts - Tooltip Visibility](http://ahumbleopinion.com/customizing-highcharts-tooltip-visibility/)

Comment: This fix is unfortunately not working in IE8. It gives error saying tooltip is null or nor found. When I refresh the page, it starts working. Any idea on this?

Comment: Let me have a look, but I'll also suggest submitting a separate question, as comments are not searchable and hence people having similar problems may miss the solution if any provided in comments

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383156/highchart-tooltip-object-is-not-found-on-the-very-next-line-in-ie8) is the new question posted

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have IE8 and the issue isn't reproducing in chrome's IE Tab in IE8 mode too, console log?

Comment: I did not find the `refresh` function in the API reference so I am very grateful for this answer.

Comment: @nilsole glad it was what you were looking for. Yes, not everything is documented, sometimes you run into several useful things while debugging.