# HighChart 'tooltip' object is not found on the very next line in IE8

Tags: jquery-ui, highcharts

I am using HighCharts with JQuery (ASP.Net, C#, MVC) to show chart on my web page. I have used below code to display the tooltip initially when page loads. Also to keep the tooltip and crosshair when mouse moves out of chart area. Thanks to answer by @jugal-thakkar

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
... <my chart options go here>
...
});

...
chart.tooltip.refresh([chart.series[0].points[1]]);
chart.tooltip.hide = function () { };
chart.tooltip.hideCrosshairs = function () { };
```

Referring to my earlier post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349249/show-highcharts-tooltip-when-chart-loads/12350047#12350047), I am facing problem with IE8 browser. The tooltip object is not found when I load the page first time. Then after refreshing the page, it starts working fine.

Am I missing any IE8 fix here? Wondering why it does not find the tooltip object only at first time!

Here is the Console Log in F12 on IE8:

```
'tooltip' is null or not an object
```

Comment: Click F12 in IE8 and see if the console has any logs? If so please paste it here, as many people may not have IE8

Comment: can u try using the load event instead of writing the statements below the constructor? http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.events.load you can use the `this` for referring to the the chart object inside the handler

Comment: Yes tried that option - not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tooltip object is not instantiated until the `document.onreadystatechange` is fired with a state of `complete`.

If you add the following to your code then it should defer attempting to raise the tooltip until it has been created

```
document.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', function () {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        chart.tooltip.refresh([chart.series[0].points[1]]);
        chart.tooltip.hide = function () { };
        chart.tooltip.hideCrosshairs = function () { };
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks good idea. My chart variable is in separate js file which I refer in my cshtml. To implement this solution, I will need to declare it globally. right? As this code will go into documetn.ready?

Comment: You could do document.chart = chart. That would make it easily accessible.