# Is it possible to select a specific point in javascript HighCharts programatically?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Assuming I have the following:

http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

Notice that when you hover on the chart, you can see a vertical line through the "column" where your mouse is hovered over.

Is there some function or method I can call so that I can click a button and have the vertical column/selected datapoint be triggered programatically without having to hover the mouse over the graph itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show HighCharts tooltip when chart loads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349249/show-highcharts-tooltip-when-chart-loads)

Comment: Using the information from the link above, I created this for you:  http://jsfiddle.net/6vjZY/